# I am getting following error while restarting MariaDBgallera cluster''WSREP has not yet prepared node for application use''

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mariadb

I am running MariaDB Gallera 10.0 in Ubuntu 14.04 Server with 3 node, While Data inserting happening in the server if I restart the mysql server in any of the 3 nodes I am Unable to bring back the server to the cluster.

```
Error:ERROR 1047 (08S01): WSREP has not yet prepared node for application use
```

I can start the mysql server, but WSREP is not showing READY

```
root@ip-172-31-3-97:~# service mysql start
 * Starting MariaDB database server mysqld                                                                                              [ OK ] 
 * Checking for corrupt, not cleanly closed and upgrade needing tables.
root@ip-172-31-3-97:~# ERROR 1047 (08S01) at line 1: WSREP has not yet prepared node for application use
```

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show status like "wsrep%";
+------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                | Value                                                |
+------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| wsrep_local_state_uuid       | 8b2b70a9-d646-11e5-a275-022c471b9ae2                 |
| wsrep_protocol_version       | 7                                                    |
| wsrep_last_committed         | 1499108                                              |
| wsrep_replicated             | 0                                                    |
| wsrep_replicated_bytes       | 0                                                    |
| wsrep_repl_keys              | 0                                                    |
| wsrep_repl_keys_bytes        | 0                                                    |
| wsrep_repl_data_bytes        | 0                                                    |
| wsrep_repl_other_bytes       | 0                                                    |
| wsrep_received               | 1                                                    |
| wsrep_received_bytes         | 276                                                  |
| wsrep_local_commits          | 0                                                    |
| wsrep_local_cert_failures    | 0                                                    |
| wsrep_local_replays          | 0                                                    |
| wsrep_local_send_queue       | 0                                                    |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_max   | 1                                                    |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_min   | 0                                                    |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_avg   | 0.000000                                             |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue       | 0                                                    |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_max   | 1                                                    |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_min   | 0                                                    |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg   | 0.000000                                             |
| wsrep_local_cached_downto    | 18446744073709551615                                 |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused_ns | 0                                                    |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused    | 0.000000                                             |
| wsrep_flow_control_sent      | 0                                                    |
| wsrep_flow_control_recv      | 0                                                    |
| wsrep_cert_deps_distance     | 0.000000                                             |
| wsrep_apply_oooe             | 0.000000                                             |
| wsrep_apply_oool             | 0.000000                                             |
| wsrep_apply_window           | 0.000000                                             |
| wsrep_commit_oooe            | 0.000000                                             |
| wsrep_commit_oool            | 0.000000                                             |
| wsrep_commit_window          | 0.000000                                             |
| wsrep_local_state            | 1                                                    |
| wsrep_local_state_comment    | Joining: receiving State Transfer                    |
| wsrep_cert_index_size        | 0                                                    |
| wsrep_causal_reads           | 0                                                    |
| wsrep_cert_interval          | 0.000000                                             |
| wsrep_incoming_addresses     | 172.31.3.97:3306,172.31.28.172:3306,172.31.3.98:3306 |
| wsrep_evs_delayed            |                                                      |
| wsrep_evs_evict_list         |                                                      |
| wsrep_evs_repl_latency       | 0/0/0/0/0                                            |
| wsrep_evs_state              | OPERATIONAL                                          |
| wsrep_gcomm_uuid             | aa655de3-d6fc-11e5-8326-02f5d924b426                 |
| wsrep_cluster_conf_id        | 5                                                    |
| wsrep_cluster_size           | 3                                                    |
| wsrep_cluster_state_uuid     | 8b2b70a9-d646-11e5-a275-022c471b9ae2                 |
| wsrep_cluster_status         | Primary                                              |
| wsrep_connected              | ON                                                   |
| wsrep_local_bf_aborts        | 0                                                    |
| wsrep_local_index            | 0                                                    |
| wsrep_provider_name          | Galera                                               |
| wsrep_provider_vendor        | Codership Oy <info@codership.com>                    |
| wsrep_provider_version       | 3.9(rXXXX)                                           |
| wsrep_ready                  | OFF                                                  |
| wsrep_thread_count           | 2                                                    |
+------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
57 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Following is my cluster.cnf

```
root@ip-172-31-3-97:~# cat /etc/mysql/conf.d/cluster.cnf 
[mysqld]
query_cache_size=0
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
query_cache_type=0
#bind-address=0.0.0.0

# Galera Provider Configuration
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size=2G"

# Galera Cluster Configuration
wsrep_cluster_name="Auth_User Cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://172.31.28.172"

# Galera Synchronization Congifuration
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
#wsrep_sst_auth=user:pass

# Galera Node Configuration
wsrep_node_address="172.31.3.97"
wsrep_node_name=Maria2"
```

log from the 172.31.28.172 server.

```
Feb 19 11:39:42 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:42 [Note] WSREP: (bac5684c, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting on, nonlive peers: tcp://172.31.3.97:4567 
Feb 19 11:39:44 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:44 [Note] WSREP: (bac5684c, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') reconnecting to aa655de3 (tcp://172.31.3.97:4567), attempt 0
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: evs::proto(bac5684c, GATHER, view_id(REG,aa655de3,5)) suspecting node: aa655de3
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: evs::proto(bac5684c, GATHER, view_id(REG,aa655de3,5)) suspected node without join message, declaring inactive
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: declaring cc5d820a at tcp://172.31.3.98:4567 stable
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: Node bac5684c state prim
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(PRIM,bac5684c,6) memb {
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011bac5684c,0
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011cc5d820a,0
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: } joined {
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: } left {
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: } partitioned {
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011aa655de3,0
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: })
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: save pc into disk
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = yes, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 0, memb_num = 2
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: forgetting aa655de3 (tcp://172.31.3.97:4567)
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: (bac5684c, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting off
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: STATE_EXCHANGE: sent state UUID: 7ac8b609-d6fd-11e5-9a9c-96322f9cb198
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: sent state msg: 7ac8b609-d6fd-11e5-9a9c-96322f9cb198
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 7ac8b609-d6fd-11e5-9a9c-96322f9cb198 from 0 (Maria1")
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 7ac8b609-d6fd-11e5-9a9c-96322f9cb198 from 1 (Maria3")
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011version    = 3,
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011component  = PRIMARY,
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011conf_id    = 5,
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011members    = 2/2 (joined/total),
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011act_id     = 1499548,
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011last_appl. = 1499416,
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011protocols  = 0/7/3 (gcs/repl/appl),
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011group UUID = 8b2b70a9-d646-11e5-a275-022c471b9ae2
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [23, 23]
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: 8b2b70a9-d646-11e5-a275-022c471b9ae2:1499548, view# 6: Primary, number of nodes: 2, my index: 0, protocol version 3
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: REPL Protocols: 7 (3, 2)
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 1499548, protocol version: 3
Feb 19 11:39:47 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
Feb 19 11:39:50 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:50 [Note] WSREP:  cleaning up aa655de3 (tcp://172.31.3.97:4567)
Feb 19 11:39:52 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:52 [Note] WSREP: (bac5684c, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting on, nonlive peers: 

Feb 19 11:39:52 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:52 [Note] WSREP: declaring aa655de3 at tcp://172.31.3.97:4567 stable
Feb 19 11:39:52 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:52 [Note] WSREP: declaring cc5d820a at tcp://172.31.3.98:4567 stable
Feb 19 11:39:52 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:52 [Note] WSREP: Node bac5684c state prim
Feb 19 11:39:52 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:52 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(PRIM,aa655de3,7) memb {
Feb 19 11:39:52 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011aa655de3,0
Feb 19 11:39:52 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011bac5684c,0
Feb 19 11:39:52 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011cc5d820a,0
Feb 19 11:39:52 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: } joined {
Feb 19 11:39:52 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: } left {
Feb 19 11:39:52 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: } partitioned {
Feb 19 11:39:52 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: })
Feb 19 11:39:52 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:52 [Note] WSREP: save pc into disk
Feb 19 11:39:52 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:52 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = yes, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 1, memb_num = 3
Feb 19 11:39:52 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:52 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: Waiting for state UUID.
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:53 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: sent state msg: 7dd70ac6-d6fd-11e5-b460-6e9ef4e0c8c7
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:53 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 7dd70ac6-d6fd-11e5-b460-6e9ef4e0c8c7 from 0 (Maria2")
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:53 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 7dd70ac6-d6fd-11e5-b460-6e9ef4e0c8c7 from 1 (Maria1")
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:53 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 7dd70ac6-d6fd-11e5-b460-6e9ef4e0c8c7 from 2 (Maria3")
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:53 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011version    = 3,
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011component  = PRIMARY,
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011conf_id    = 6,
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011members    = 2/3 (joined/total),
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011act_id     = 1499548,
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011last_appl. = 1499416,
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011protocols  = 0/7/3 (gcs/repl/appl),
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: #011group UUID = 8b2b70a9-d646-11e5-a275-022c471b9ae2
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:53 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [28, 28]
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:53 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: 8b2b70a9-d646-11e5-a275-022c471b9ae2:1499548, view# 7: Primary, number of nodes: 3, my index: 1, protocol version 3
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:53 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:53 [Note] WSREP: REPL Protocols: 7 (3, 2)
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:53 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:53 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 1499548, protocol version: 3
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:53 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.

Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:53 [Note] WSREP: Member 0.0 (Maria2") requested state transfer from '*any*'. Selected 2.0 (Maria3")(SYNCED) as donor.

Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:53 [Note] WSREP: 2.0 (Maria3"): State transfer to 0.0 (Maria2") complete.
Feb 19 11:39:53 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:53 [Note] WSREP: Member 2.0 (Maria3") synced with group.

Feb 19 11:39:56 ip-172-31-28-172 mysqld: 160219 11:39:56 [Note] WSREP: (bac5684c, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting off
```

Please provide a solution for this.